# Android Login to website using webview

Tags: php, android, authentication, laravel, webview

We have our website built in Laravel 3.0 framework in php. We are now developing android app for the website. 
Now the question is that we haven't used oAuth or oAuth2.0 like authentication in our backend.

Now I was wondering the approaches in order to login to backend.

1. Display webview at the start of the app for a single time with `Login` URL and then use stored cookies to manage further authentication requirements.
2. Using custom elements for login credentials like `email` and `password` and then call the `NameValuePair` service to log in to the backend. (But problem with this approach is that we need to send `csfr_token` in with `email` and `password` that is not available to user.
3. Or is there any other methods or practices available to `login` and stayed `logged in` in android app for the `php` based backend.

I was searching a bit about this in stackoverflow and google and I found this app called `SeriesGuide` which uses `webview` to login to their backend and then stayed `Logged in` until `Logged Out`. Please guide us for the query and Pardon my informal language and english.